# How to grab keyboard events on an element which doesn't accept focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, keyboard-events

I know that for handling keyboard events in an input field you can use:

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
var code = e.keyCode // and 13 is the keyCode for Enter
});
```

But, now, I have some `div` and `li` elements, and I don't have a `form` element, and none of my elements are considered to be form elements and none of them accept **focus** or **tab** and stuff like that.

But now I need to handle the `keyup` (or `keydown`, or `keypress`, doesn't matter) event in a div element. I tried:

```
$('div#modal').keyup(function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == 13)
   {
      $('#next').click(); // Mimicking mouse click to go to the next level.
   }
});
```

But the problem is, it doesn't work.
What should I do?

Comment: I don't understand how can you catch keyup in the element, that don't have focus..

Comment: Agreed - need to have some idea of how the user is going to interact with a non-interactive element with a keyboard.

Comment: @kinakuta & @Igor Dymov - You can use the `tabindex` attribute to make a `div` accept focus. See my answer.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

A `div` by default cannot be given focus. However, you can change that by adding a `tabindex` attribute to the `div`:

```
<div tabindex="0" id="example"></div>
```

You can then give the `div` focus, and also blur it with the `hover` event:

```
$("#example").hover(function() {
    this.focus();
}, function() {
    this.blur();
}).keydown(function(e) {
    alert(e.keyCode);
});
```

When the `div` has focus, it will accept keyboard events. You can see an example of this working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/erCEq/).

Comment: You need `$(this).focus()` to get the jQuery object, not the DOM element.  Ditto for `.blur()`.  But, yes, with a tabindex attribute you then get key events.  Thanks!

Comment: You, kind Sir, just made my day!!!  Had given up on binding on a DIV a while back, until I came across your solution to this issue!!

Comment: Note: `tabindex=0` means that the element should be focusable in sequential keyboard navigation, but its order is defined by the document's source order. [(source)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex#wikiArticle) Thus, you can assign it to multiple elements without problems.

Answer (score 6):

I'm late but the correct way to ensure the proper event fire now is by using the HTML5 new attribute "contenteditable":

```
<div id="myEditableDiv" contenteditable="true"> txt_node </div>
```

classic Js mechanic can then be applied:

```
var el = document.getElementById('myEditableDiv');
el.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){console.log(e.target.innerText);});
el.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){console.log(e.target.innerText);});
el.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){console.log(e.target.innerText);});
```

Comment: Why would you make the div editable? By setting `contenteditable=true`, the text inside the div becomes editable. I don't think you want to do that just to get the keyboard events to work.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. (Here another for you, how to know the div has focus?)
As I can see, your div is a popup (its id is `dialog`).
Here you have a workaround:

On popup open:

```
$("div#modal").data("isOpen", true);
```

On poup close:

```
$("div#modal").data("isOpen", false);
```

Then, the binding:

```
$('body').keyup(function(e){  //Binding to body (it accepts key events)
   if($("div#modal").data("isOpen")){  //Means we're in the dialog
       if (e.keyCode == 13) //This keyup would be in the div dialog
       {
          $('#next').click(); // Mimicking mouse click to go to the next level.
       }
   }
});
```

This way, we're mimicking keyup event on the div.
Hope this helps. Cheers

PS: Note that you can use `#dialog` instead of `div#dialog`