# keypress in jquery modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-dialog

I opened a jquery modal dialog which has 2 textboxes and a button

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><input name="" type="text" value="" title="User Name" class="width190 enter_popup" id="txtUserName" onfocus="txtFocus(this)" onblur="txtFBlur(this,'0')"/></td>
          <td align="center"><input name="" type="password" value=""  title="Password" class="width190 enter_popup" id="txtPassword" onfocus="txtFocus(this)" onblur="txtFBlur(this,'1')"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="" type="submit" class="blue_btn" value="Sign In"  id="btnLogIn" onclick="javascript:return LogIn()"/></td>
        </tr>

      </table>
```

now in my script I'm calling LogIn function

```
$(function () {

    $(".enter_popup").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            if ($(this).attr('id') == "txtUserName" || $(this).attr('id') == "txtPassword") {
                LogIn();
            }

        }
    });
 });

function LogIn() {
    var username = $('#txtUserName').val();
    var password = $('#txtPassword').val();
}
```

but keypress is not fired..any ideas why and what is possible solution for that?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/dzxu1c8s/ so i'm guessing that the element is dynamically created thus needing `event-delegation`  `$(document).on('keypress','.enter_popup',function(){/*code*/});`

Comment: also verified that your code is working. try Anton's solution above.

Comment: @Anton: this `$(document).on('keypress','.enter_popup',function(){/*code*/});` worked for me.. post it as answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [detect key press on modal dialog not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351044/detect-key-press-on-modal-dialog-not-working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use event-delegation on dynamically created elements

```
$(document).on('keypress','.enter_popup',function(){
    /*Your code*/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use the Keydown or Keyup events instead:

```
$(function () {

$(".enter_popup").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == "txtUserName" || $(this).attr('id') == "txtPassword") {
            LogIn();
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it a better solution to give focus to the modal, it worked for me.

In order to do that, you have to add a `tabindex` parameter to your modal container, and then set its focus using JavaScript. Once that's done it can receive keyboard events: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633271/2873507