# detect key press on modal dialog not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I would like to detect whether the user has pressed any key when a modal is shown. I tried the following code but the events are not fired.

Code snippet:

```
   $("#modal_confirmation_dp_change").on('keydown keyup input', function ( e ) {
         alert();
        });
```

If I try to test click event, it is fired.

```
   $("#modal_confirmation_dp_change").on('click', function ( e ) {
            alert();
        });
```

I am using twitter bootstrap modal. Am I missing something?

**ANSWER:**
I found the solution to my problem. It seems like I should not point to the id of the modal so that the keypress event will be detected.

Comment: how is the modal created? have you put a breakpoint in the event to see if it is fired?

Comment: I am using twitter bootstrap modal. I tried putting a breakpoint in that function but it was not fired. Click event, on the other hand, is fired.

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315820/jquery-script-adding-id-and-using-it-doesnt-work/34316271#34316271

Comment: can you put your html code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. It seems like I should not point to the id of the modal so that the keypress event will be detected.

```
$(document).on('keydown keyup input click',  function (e) {
if($('#modal_confirmation_dp_change').is(':visible')) {
            var key = e.which;
                if (key == 13) { //This is an ENTER 
                    $('#changed_dp_ok').click();
                }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use multiple events like this, because it would fire three times as per count of your events one for `keydown` and for `keyup` and one for `input`. Still this is not issue, the issue is the `click` you are triggering. That is the event of jQuery event object, While you need to fire the `click` on the DOM.

You should fire the native `.click()` event of DOM:

```
$("#modal_confirmation_dp_change").on('keydown', function ( e ) {
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (key == 13) {
        $('#changed_dp_ok')[0].click(); // <----use the DOM click this way!!!
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    //$('.btn').click();  // <----this wont work
    $('.btn')[0].click(); // <---but this works
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: check the snippet added.

Answer (score 0):

I find it a better solution to give focus to the modal.

In order to do that, you have to add a `tabindex` parameter to your modal container, and then set its focus using JavaScript. Once that's done it can receive keyboard events: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633271/2873507