# How to capture a keydown event on jointjs paper?

Tags: jointjs

There seems to be no [keydown](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.0/joint.html#dia.Paper.events) event associated with jointjs paper. How we can capture such event ?

Solutions that I tried:

Solution 1: Capture keydown on the div element (which holds paper). It didn't work.

```
$('#myholder).on('keydown', (e) => {
    console.log(e.which);
});
```

Solution 2: It seems a bit tough.

```
$(document).on('keydown', (e) => {
if( the previous event fired in 'blank:pointerdown' on paper and no other event is fired after that [which is equivalent to keydown on paper]) {
    console.log(e.which);
}
```

});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer in this question does the trick [How to grab keyboard events on an element which doesn't accept focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633248/how-to-grab-keyboard-events-on-an-element-which-doesnt-accept-focus)

```
$('#paper')
    .attr('tabindex', 0)
    .on('mouseover', function() {
        this.focus();
    })
    .on('keydown', function(e) {
        console.log(e.which);
    });
```

Also in the RappidJS (framework bases on the JointJS) there is the ui.Keyboard plugin which makes the keyboard handling easier http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v2.1/ui.html#ui.Keyboard